# Creating own checked exceptions

Tags: java

For what I know you use checked exceptions when you have an error that your applciation can recover from. However, some of the errors that occur in my application does not fit the exceptions that are already made by Sun. Is it ok to create domain specific checked exceptions (bad practise?)? For instance: DuplicateQuestionException --> thrown when the application recieves two equal questions. This is a case that my application can recover from.

Comment: Yes. It is perfectly fine. What will be good to see how you have created custom exception?

Comment: Its good practice to create user defined checked exceptions from which you can recover and continue with the application code.

Comment: You could instead provide a method to check if it is ok to add a question `if (!Questions.isDuplicate(newQuestion)) { Questions.add(newQuestion); }` and throw an unchecked exception, say an `IllegalArgumentException` if a duplicate question is created. This might not be applicable to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

yes that is good practice.  don't try to force using an existing exception if it doesn't make sense in your domain.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is better it you create own exception, rather than use raw exception. and when you will be creating your own exceptions, don't forget about exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is good to use checked exceptions when the application can reasonably recover, and it's perfectly reasonable and indicated to use custom checked exceptions when Java doesn't provide fit ones.

Strait from Effective Java second edition by Josh Bloch:

from item 58 about throwing checked exceptions:

"The cardinal rule in deciding whether to use a checked or an unchecked
exception is this: use checked exceptions for conditions from which the caller
can reasonably be expected to recover."

from item 60 about extending existing exceptions:

"Also, feel free to subclass an existing exception if you want to add a bit more failure-capture information."